# Android HTTP Request for CakePHP URL

Tags: android, httpwebrequest, http-post, urlencode, http-get

I have a website which was created with cakephp. I want to pass some values formed in my App to this website. When I enter the exact same URL in the browser it works.

The URL is something like: www.something.com/function/add/value

So I'm very confused if this is a GET or a POST method? And how I can do that?

The thing is that I can NOT change this URL or put some POST or GET PHP script there to get the values. So I basically just have to call the URL with those params.

This is my code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = null;
try {
        httppost = new HttpPost("www.something.com/function/add/" + URLEncoder.encode(txtMessage.getText().toString(), "UTF-8"));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
}

try {
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `List<NameValuePair>` and put here yours values ("somevalue" in example). Create `DefaultHttpClient()` set `nameValuePairs` with yours value.

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", "TEST_TAG"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("valueKey", "somevalue"));
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("www.something.com/function/add/utils.php");
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream is = entity.getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = "";
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line + "n");
}
is.close();
Log.i("response", sb.toString());
```

On the server side in `/function/add/utils.php` get yours value

```
if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') {
     $tag = $_POST['tag']; //=TEST_TAG
     $value = $_POST['valueKey']; //=somevalue
}
//and return some info 
$response = array("tag" => $tag, "success" => 0, "error" => 0);
$response["success"] = 1;
echo json_encode($response);
```

This `$response` you recive in your java code as `HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity()`. It may help you.

Comment: well I'm sorry I think 8 wasn't clear enough. My url does not include a PHP file or anything. Just a plain URL (The way CakePHP creates them...) The server reads the value from the URL directly. Is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: You have a link like `www.something.com/function/add/` with some values. Try to find handler-file on the server. In this directory `function/add/` must be `index.php`. Is there?

Comment: No there is no PHP file and there is no way that there is ever going to be one. The link www.something.com/function/add/myvaluetobeadded is there that way. CakePHP then knows that "myvaluetobeadded" is the actual value I give to the website, If I navigate to the website with a browser it works great.

Comment: ok, i understand. The way with `DefaultHttpClient()` isnt right. I dont think exactly that this can solve your problem but look how to follow a link. Like a `WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView); Uri data = Uri.parse("http://www.site.com")); webView.loadUrl(data.toString());` - but this is through opening browser...

Comment: Would this also be possible in the background somewhere and without opening the browser?