# How to Get a JSON Response from WordPress Site?

Tags: android, wordpress

I am using WordPress in my site. The response I am getting from the server is HTML.

What do I need to do to get a server response in JSON format?

Comment: i think it belongs to [wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: No need to add code in WordPress. Use Jetpack JSON API http://jetpack.me/support/json-api/.

Comment: @AMYunus, I think this should be an Answer as it is *on target*. It doesn't look like the OP knows how to program *("where to put the code?" - [first version](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13468145/revisions) of the Q)*.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here [Android HTTP Request for CakePHP URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267806/android-http-request-for-cakephp-url/13268739#13268739) , it's not exactly the same but to close to your question.